# sidebar collapse status, save cookie

Tags: jquery, html, css, cookies, sidebar

this question follows my previous post located here:

[jquery sliding side bar right to left with resizing content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043344/jquery-sliding-side-bar-right-to-left-with-resizing-content)

I have managed to get the sidebar how i want, but now i want it to save the cookie of the state the sidebar is in (whether its collapsed, or expaned.) so when the user refreshes the page it's still collapsed/expanded depending on what they decide to do =)

jsfiddle.net/ZL56h/

jsfiddle does not display it correctly so alternatively you can view/download what i have so far here

http://www.mediafire.com/view/zor5r5utm6v394t/Sidebar.htm

Comment: "You can download what I have so far here" seriously?

Comment: Please provide the code in your question and if possible with JSfiddle.

Comment: there's simply too much for a little jsfiddle, mediafire actually displays the code elegantly and you can hit the DL button and even open it up for yourself to actually see whats rly going on rather than a little box on jsfiddle.  and the way all this is set up... i dont think it would even run properaly on jsfiddle but ill see if i can get one going if itll make you guys happy.... rly though, itd be so much easier for people to just d/l my html, and open it in their browser -_-